# Add custom attributes in Customer form registration

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer-account

I followed this article http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-1-3-how-to-make-customer-attribute-update.html  to add 3 attributes
this is My Install.php

```
<?php

namespace Magenticians\CustomerAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'birth', [
            'type' => 'static',
            'label' => 'Birth',
            'input' => 'date',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'adresse', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Adresse',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1001,
            'position' => 1001,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Phone Number',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'validate_rules' => '{"max_text_length":255,"min_text_length":1}',
            'sort_order' => 1002,
            'position' => 1002,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);



        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'birth')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create'],
            ]);

        $secondattribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'adresse')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create'],
            ]);


        $thirdattribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
        $secondattribute->save();
        $thirdattribute->save();



    }
}
```

I also added to `register.phtml`

```
 <div class="field required">
            <label for="adresse" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Adresse') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getAdresse()) ?>" title="
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Adresse') ?>" class="input-text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required">
            <label for="birth" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Birth') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="date" name="birth" id="birth" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getBirth()) ?>" title="
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Birth') ?>" class="input-text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required">
            <label for="phone" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getPhone()) ?>" title="
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text" pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}' >
            </div>
        </div>
```

I got this error when I tried to add new customer:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sajjada_site.customer_entity_date' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `customer_entity_date`
```

please help me figure out the problem and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a mistake.

For attribute `birth`, the type should be

datetime`'type' => 'datetime'`

instead of

date `'type' => 'date'`

If you have checked the  error

```
 'sajjada_site.customer_entity_date' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `customer_entity_date`
```

then you have found that **customer_entity_date** table does not exist at the database for a Magento eav module.

Usually, Magento use `customer_entity_datetime` for date save types attribute value for customer entity.

Comment: I  remplaced date by datetime and i just run upgrade, indexer:reindex flush but same error

Comment: i just removed the module and increased module 1.0.3 and it works well